# What's the name of this traffic-control structure found at some checkpoints?

Tags: transportation, driving, security, terminology

At some security checkpoints around New York there is a kind of barrier whose name I'm interested in learning. I've attached two images.

The barrier is a sheet of metal raised a foot or two on one side. If a vehicle is approved to enter, the sheet of metal can be lowered to be flush with the street. (Prior research: I've tried extensive search-engine searches with text and these images. I'm not sure if there's a better SE forum to post on, but Travel seems the closest.)

What is this called?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking at is often referred to as a [hydraulic road blocker](https://www.google.fr/search?q=one-way%20traffic%20flow%20plates&biw=2560&bih=1276&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIkqiEl-j-yAIVCsAUCh2wVwJd#tbm=isch&q=hydraulic%20road%20blocker), or an [anti-ram barrier](https://www.google.fr/search?q=one-way+traffic+flow+plates&biw=2560&bih=1276&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIkqiEl-j-yAIVCsAUCh2wVwJd#tbm=isch&q=anti-ram+barrier). These are somewhat like an extension of the concept [one-way plates](https://www.google.fr/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=2560&bih=1276&q=traffic%20plates&oq=traffic%20plates&gs_l=img.3..0j0i8i30.2093.3434.0.3484.14.12.0.2.2.0.93.615.12.12.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.14.623._1EQK2ncEnE#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=one-way%20traffic%20plates) in that their purpose is similar: they both aim at blocking traffic.

Comment: Yes- and note only the right image shows the "oncoming" view.